# Word doesn't work in the server side if I am not logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, ms-office, dcom

When I tried to open a word application on the server by

```
 Application ap = new Application();
```

I got this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the
>   configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).

If I logged in a remote connection and tried it will work but when I disconnect it will not.

It think it is a security and permission issue but I don't know where. I am using IIS 8 and windows server 2012.

Don't try to suggest to use OpenXml or say that Microsoft doesn't recommend that, I want to use Microsoft Office 2013.

Comment: Using Office automation on the server side is neither recommended nor supported. You should have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 for more information.

Comment: What you're trying to do is rather tricky, and will never work reliably.  Don't do that.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry, I want to do it and I am sure there is a way to do it

Comment: There are very good reasons that `Microsoft doesn't recommend that`.

Comment: @kartal: The reliable way to do that is to rewrite Office to not be coupled to a UI.  Good luck with that.

Comment: You are using IIS web application to launch word?  Have you checked the user and permission of the assigned app pool for your application?  Sounds like it could be a permission issue.

Comment: We had so much fun with a server installation of MS Office, we had all sorts of watchdogs to monitor and restart crashed or hung instances, but even then every now and then the watchdogs themselves would end up being hung.

Comment: @Newse I know it is a permission issue but where and how to fix it ?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @kartal - IIS Web Applications inherit their permissions from their assigned app pool.  By default an app pool will have limited capabilites outside of IIS.  The first place I would start when troubleshooting this issue - is to verify that your IIS app pool is assigned to a user account on your platforms that has the proper permissions.    I've done word automation through a windows service and didn't have any issues with permissions but the service ran under a dedicated user account.

Comment: @kartal: you may very well want to do it. But if someone told me that they want to jump in front of a moving train, I would recommend against it. Same here.

Comment: Voting to close as I don't really see how one can provide good and reliable answer to this question short of "don't do it" (which is already ruled out by OP).

Comment: I already did it by using a third party app always working in the server